# How to distribute IOC/DI components over several machines?

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap, distribution

I'm maintaining a large application that makes heavy use of StructureMap to load it's components. I'm trying to split the components up so they can run on different machines, connected via network. They already run in different threads, but within the same process (making use of a single StructureMap container).

I'm not sure how to do this. Is it possible to have StructureMap automatically create a proxy for all components and use them over network instead of locally? What changes to the components are needed to make them distributable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting! Theoretically I guess it is possible, the real underlying question is if you really want to do so, we are talking about a major architectural change.

Disclaimer: I don't know how familiar you are with WCF, I'll attempt to explain very roughly how I imagine it being possible, but consider that if we are talking about this sort of communication over a network you want to use WCF.

- Define every interface for the components that you want to use over a network as a WCF service contract
- Wrap your components with services and host them somewhere/somehow
- Write clients for these services, having them implement your components interfaces
- Let StructureMap inject your clients when the code expects a component

While it sounds quite straightforward, a relevant complexity is hiding behind these steps. To name a few potential issues off the top of my head: which components are you going to wrap into services? How easy is wrapping them going to be? Where are you going to host them, how? What about security? Does your logging mechanism need to be adjusted?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with WCF. This is pretty much the approach I considered :) However, I'm not very familiar with StructureMap - but from what you wrote I assume that SM does not provide means to automate the steps you outlined, so I have to implement them myself and let SM know to use the WCF clients instead of the service instances themselves. I would also have to provide a different manager for the services themselves because SM does not allow remote service management, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: SM is simply an IoC Container, I don't know of any container that makes your instances magically remote, since it is a complex process that can hardly be automated (see previous list of concerns). So yes, you should wire SM so that it uses client proxies instead of component instances; if for manager you mean host, yes you also need to set up an host for your services.